# 2D-Array to tiled map PyGame, Python

Tags: python, 2d, tile

I have looked for similar questions, but I haven't found anything concrete enough to actually apply to my situation.

Ok, so I've come up with something that will display the right amount of images, in the right places, except for the Y axis.
Basically, if I have array:

```
[1,1,1,1,
 0,0,0,0]
```

I would want it to display as something like:

```
####
@@@@
```

However, it display as this:

```
####@@@@
```

How do I iterate down in the rows, much more importantly, how do I detect a row-continuation?

Comment: Is the problem solved? Add it as an answer instead and accept. This way the question doesn't remain unanswered. Also, it may be a _TAD_ presumptuous to think the internet will jump on your problem on a Saturday night in less than an hour. Give it some time!

Comment: Hmm, not sure how to change this to an answer, any suggestions?

Comment: I'll post it as a community wiki (that way I don't get any credit). Just accept it when it comes up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting on behalf of the OP who is new to the site and found the answer on their own.

```
tileX = 0
tileY = 0
tile_dict = {0: pygame.image.load("C:\Users\Software Development\Desktop\Tile00.png"),    1: pygame.image.load("C:\Users\Software Development\Desktop\Tile01.png")}

map00 = [[0,0,0,0],
    [1,1,1,1], [1,0,1,0]]

for x in map00:
for x in x:
    if x == 0:
        screen.blit(tile_dict[0], (tileX, tileY))
        tileX = tileX+16
    if x == 1:
        screen.blit(tile_dict[1], (tileX, tileY))
        tileX = tileX+16
tileX = 0
tileY += 16
```

Comment: @FrigidDev Welcome to Stack Overflow. You'll get a much better response in the future if you follow the rules (see HELP). If you want a faster response, ask a single, simple, pointed question with a minimal working example. Also, it helps to ask during prime time hours too.